# create hyperlink using dust templating engine

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, express, dust.js

Does somebody know how can we create a hyperlink using dust.js with node.js?

I want to create links on my webpage, but simple hyperlinks are not working.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Show some code indicating what you've tried, and specify what you want it to do and what it isn't doing.

Comment: I wanted to see how hyperlinks can be added to my views. I know it supports simple <a> tags in .dust files. I tried to use one on official dust website just to know if it creates a hyperlink for me. On http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/, i selected "plain" template from dropdown and made following changes to its text:                                                                       <a href="www.youtube.com">Hello World!</a>

Comment: but it shows me the same thing as rendered output. Please tell me what i am missing.. :(

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual code you wrote. That way we can either spot the problem right away, or try it on our own systems so we can debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. We can use simple  tags in dust too as can create simple hyperlinks as we do in html.

like `<a href="products">Link</a>`